TeXShop Spelling Error Underline Color
When a word is misspelled in TeXShop, the editor underlines it in red. Which setting should I tweak to select another color to underline? I don't seem to find which Theme item corresponds to it.

I don't think there's a way to change this. It's not in the Theme setup and not in the Hidden Preferences either.
